# Why isn't my class variable being set after calling database.child("users").observeSingleEvent() from FirebaseDatabase in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When using the function database.child("users").observeSingleEvent() from FirebaseDatabase, I am able to retrieve the expected results but not save it in a class variable of a different class.

I have a method in a Database Manager that getAllUsers from my database. I have seen this works as expected

```
public func getAllUsers(completion: @escaping (Result<[[String: String]], Error>) -> Void) {
        database.child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            guard let value = snapshot.value as? [[String: String]] else {
                completion(.failure(DatabaseError.failedToFetch))
                return
            }
            
            completion(.success(value))
        })
    }
```

I call this method from a Controller class function that is supposed to update my TableView.

```
 private var matches = [[String: String]]()
 
private func updateTable() {
        DatabaseManager.shared.getAllUsers(completion: { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let usersCollection):
                print("users is set here")
                print(usersCollection)
                self?.matches = usersCollection
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Failed to get users: \(error)")
            }
        })
        
        print(matches.count)
        if matches.isEmpty {
            tableView.isHidden = true
        }
        else {
            tableView.isHidden = false
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Through print statements I see the expected user list is being received with usersCollections, I set my private class variable with self?.matches, however when I go to check if that variable is set after the method call, it is still emtpy. I am confused what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You need the print and reload etc *inside* the closure. The completion handler will execute asynchronously once the fetch is complete. This takes time. You are reloading the table before the fetch is complete.

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you! I moved the if-else statement inside the .success block and is working as expected!